# Allow accented characters for Email Address Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am using the following Regex to validate an email address.  How do allow accented characters through?

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%*/?\|\^\{\}`~&'+\-=_])+(\.([a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%*/?\|\^\{\}`~&'+\-=_])+)*@((\[(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5]))\]))|((([a-zA-Z0-9])+(([\-])+([a-zA-Z0-9])+)*\.)+([a-zA-Z])+(([\-])+([a-zA-Z0-9])+)*))$
```

Here is the email address being validated:
äöüéè@paris.com

I ended up modifying the regular expression to use a \w instead of A-Za-z0-9 which will allow international characters through in C#.

```
^([\w!#\$%*/?\|\^\{\}`~&'+\-=_])+(\.([\w!#\$%*/?\|\^\{\}`~&'+\-=_])+)*@((\[(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5]))\]))|((([\w])+(([\-])+([\w])+)*\.)+([a-zA-Z])+(([\-])+([\w])+)*))$
```

Comment: Just add them in the character class.

Comment: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool." [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Comment: Added C# tag.  I have been using the regex above for years.  I can't remember where I found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the accented characters in the character class:

```
[äöüéèa-zA-Z0-9!#\$%*/?\|\^\{\}`~&'+\-=_]
```

This have to be done also for the other character class.

Or if you want to deal with any language and if your regex flavor support unicode properties:

```
[\p{L}0-9!#\$%*/?\|\^\{\}`~&'+\-=_]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Toto suggested:

```
^([äöüéèa-zA-Z0-9!#\$%*/?\|\^\{\}`~&'+\-=_])+(\.([äöüéèa-zA-Z0-9!#\$%*/?\|\^\{\}`~&'+\-=_])+)*@
```

**I've snipped off the rest of the regex**, everything after @ remains.

EDIT: Please note to add those characters in both character classes if you want to stick to your regex